# Wordpress Rest API returns error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'am developing a plugin for wordpress and have trouble with the Rest API.
On my test server it works without a problem. (v4.6.6)
On a different server (v4.4.10) the API returns this error message:

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_handler","message":"
Der Handler f\u00fcr die Route ist ung\u00fcltig","data":{"status":500}}%
```

The message is in german and means "The handler for the route is invalid." Don't understand why they translate the error messages for an API. Makes no sense for me. :)

The routes on the http://domain/wp-json are equal.
Maybe an problem with the different WP versions?

Definition of the route:

```
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function(){
        register_rest_route( 'test_namespace', 'ping', array(
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => array($this, 'ping_test'),
            'permission_callback' =>  array($this, 'myhacks_permission_callback'),
        ) );
    } );
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the file? I believe the issue is coming from $this scope is wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the PHP version. I get this error on all Servers with < PHP 5.4.
That is ok for me. I updated the PHP version and now it's working.

Comment: $this is fine, mine come from using `'callback' => array($this => 'ping_test')` instead of `'callback' => array($this, 'ping_test')`

Comment: @Glen's comment did the trick for me!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. It seems that method `ping_test` cannot be private. If you change it to public, the error disappears.

Comment: This answer helped me with the same issue. I have AjaxController class registered in FrontController. In the AjaxController I register REST routes in its constructor with `'callback' => [$this,'portfolioSave',],` args array property of `register_rest_route`. My method was `protected` and it helped me when I changed it to `public`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [WordPress core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L861) and you can see that the method passed as the `callback` aka `ping_test` must be callable.

So this error triggers only when that method doesn't exist (for example I just encountered it because of a typo) or if is not accessible(like a protected or private method)